# yammer login failed : javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, authentication, yammer

I am using JavaScript SDK to fetch yammer posts on my SharePoint site. I have used login button on click of which I get popup for authentication.

When I enter the email address, it takes me to the ADFS and entering password there I am able to login and fetch posts.

The problem I am facing is that, when I use IE browser, I stuck up after login. After I enter the password, it asks me to close the window but page doesn't refresh. Even if I refresh the page I get to see login button and clicking the button again, popup opens and I get message that window is trying to close the tab and I see Yes and No buttons.

What I have tried:

1. As per different posts, if I add https://*.yammer.com to trusted sites, on some machines I can login without any error, but on some machines I still get error.
2. I tried editing the web.config file by adding following entries:

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" , "Access-Control-Max-Age" , "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"

But that didn't help.

What could be the solution for this? Also it would not be a good option to add yammer.com in trusted site as we can't tell every user to follow that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been beating my head over this problem for days and you are going to go insane when you see how easy it is to solve. You have to :

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Press "Alt" key to bring up toolbar
3. Select "Tools"
4. Select "Internet Options"
5. Select the "Security" tab
6. Select "Trusted Sites" then click the "sites" button
7. Add www.yammer.com to zone

That should work. Let me know how it goes.